# Passing a ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, python-3.x, exception

I'm trying to perform Sales Price to Cost calculations for a report. The data I'm getting is going into an Excel sheet to be passed along. The script has worked fine for weeks but recently started failing. It fails at a line that is writing data into my Excel sheet that takes two pieces of info and computes it to get my margin. The issue is my Cost isn't lower than my Sales Price (selling for a loss) and is cause my script to fail. How can I get my script to no only pass but record the equation correctly?

`ws.cell(row=x, column=y, value=(s.SalePrice - s.Cost) / s.SalePrice)`

I've imported pyxl and xlrd for my Excel sheets.

Comment: if `s.SalePrice` is 0 then you get the error you're mentionning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get occurs whenever `s.SalePrice` is 0.

You can wrap your expression inside a `try/except` block to catch and handle that error appropriately:

```
try:
    val = (s.SalePrice - s.Cost) / s.SalePrice 
except ZeroDivisionError:
    val = 'N/A'

ws.cell(row=x, column=y, value=val)
```

Replace `N/A` with any appropriate message you'd like to display in the event that `s.SalePrice` is 0.

Comment: Hey thanks for quick response! I'll give that a shot and get back to you.